# Internationalization within two classes ; resource bundle

Tags: java, internationalization, jbutton, resourcebundle

I am creating an application, with two classes - two frames. User opens the application and see frame with 3 `Jbuttons`, that mean different languages. While clicking on one particular button it is supposed to open the next frame with all labels in chosen language. The problem is, that it opens in only one language, no matter what I do. I tried many solutions but it never works. I would appreciate some code , what would help.

First class, with start frame:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javax.swing.*;
public class StartFrame extends JFrame {
public StartFrame() {
    setSize(480,360);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panelFlags = new JPanel();

    this.add(panelFlags);
    panelFlags.setBackground(Color.white);
    buttonFlagPl= new JButton(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("x.png")).getImage()).getScaledInstance(100, 75, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
    buttonFlagEn = new JButton(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("y.jpg")).getImage()).getScaledInstance(100, 75, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
    buttonFlagDe = new JButton(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("z.jpg")).getImage()).getScaledInstance(100, 75, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
    buttonFlagPl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 75));
    buttonFlagEn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 75));
    buttonFlagDe.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 75));

    panelFlags.add(buttonFlagPl);
    panelFlags.add(buttonFlagEn);
    panelFlags.add(buttonFlagDe);


    buttonFlagPl.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MainFrame mainFramePl= new MainFrame();
            mainFramePl.setVisible(true);
            mainFramePl.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainFramePl.resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels_pl", new Locale ("pl"));
            dispose();  
        }           
    });

    buttonFlagEn.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MainFrame mainFrameEn = new MainFrame();
            mainFrameEn.setVisible(true);
            mainFrameEn.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainFrameEn.resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels_en",new Locale ("en"));
            dispose();  
        }           
    });

    buttonFlagDe.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MainFrame mainFrameDe = new MainFrame();
            mainFrameDe.setVisible(true);
            mainFrameDe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainFrameDe.resourceBundle =  ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels_de",new Locale ("de"));
            dispose();  
        }           
    });
}

JPanel panelFlags;
JButton buttonFlagPl;
JButton buttonFlagEn; 
JButton buttonFlagDe; 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StartFrame startFrame = new StartFrame();
    startFrame.setVisible(true);
    startFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);     
}
}
```

And here is the part with Main Frame:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
public MainFrame(){
    super();
    setSize(1000,640);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(500,200,5));
    mainPanelColor = new Color (200,200,230);
    mainPanel.setBackground(mainPanelColor);
    buttonBackToChooseLanguage = new JButton();
 buttonBackToChooseLanguage.setText((resourceBundle).getString("button.back"));
```

(...)

```
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainFrame window = new MainFrame();
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);

}
```

I missed the rest of code on purpose. The thing is, that no matter what I put into `"ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels");"` it always gives me one and the same language for all buttons, so I assume, that lines `"mainFramePl.resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels_pl", new Locale ("pl"));"` do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the label of `buttonBackToChooseLanguage` in the `MainFrame` constructor, before you have set `resourceBundle` to your new value -- while the constructor is running it is always set to `ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels")`.

So `MainFrame` looks like:

```
MainFrame(ResourceBundle bundle) {
    resourceBundle = bundle;
    // set up the frame ...
    // set labels using resourceBundle
}
```

And your actionListeners look like:

```
buttonFlagDe.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        MainFrame mainFrameDe = new MainFrame(ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels_de",new Locale ("de")));
        mainFrameDe.setVisible(true);
        mainFrameDe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dispose();  
    }           
});
```

Comment: could you tell me, please, what could I do then?

Comment: Pass the name of the resource bundle to the MainFrame constructor and intialise `resourceBundle` in the constructor before you get any labels from it.

Comment: but passing `ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels");` to constructor will make it being invisible for StartFrame in `mainFrameEn.resourceBundle =  ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels_en",new Locale ("en"));`

Comment: Ok, I have just figure this out. But one more question - what does it mean: "initialise resourceBundle in the constructor before you get any labels...". Initialise with what? I still get one and the same language, and the `mainFrameEn.resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels_en",new Locale ("en"));` don't work. Could you explain this, please?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain exactly what you need to do